# Creating a User via api in Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am considering Keycloak as my authorization server in my backend project. The challenge is that there is a checking on an existing database to see if the details of the user is existing on that DB and also there is a creation of user from scratch (Without checking of details from that DB).

I searched for possible approach and I can create a user via API (Using Admin Account) in keycloak. I currently have Spring Boot / Java as my backend.

My question are:

1. Is creating a user via API a good practice? If not, what approach should I check? Should I use other auth server?
2. If yes, what are the things I should look out for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am creating users using REST Admin Client API. Even I am curious about the same.

Comment: Hi @PiyushChauhan do you have any implementation or approach?